# Importação circular

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

A [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/) do Flask, apesar de usar nos seus exemplos, alerta ao final da página sobre a má prática de se usar importações circulares. 
Outra coisa que me incomoda é criar "objetos globais" dentro de um arquivo `__init__.py`.

Qual seria a outra solução?

Arquivo `__init__.py` do módulo principal, ou seja, a pasta principal da aplicação:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import yourapplication.views
```

O arquivo views.py (A view da aplicação):

```
from yourapplication import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

A estrutura do projeto:

```
/yourapplication
    setup.py
    /yourapplication
        __init__.py
        views.py
        /static
            style.css
        /templates
            layout.html
            index.html
            login.html
            ...
```

*Créditos do código de exemplo: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/#simple-packages*

Comment: E por quê o objeto `app` **precisa** ser definido em `__init__.py`?

Comment: Também queria saber. Estou começando no desenvolvimento de Flask. Olhando rápido me parece que é pelo fato de que o `__init__.py` é chamado no momento que o módulo é importado ai o objeto seria criado.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, o flask tem a intenção de ser completamente modularizado e livre para que você se sinta à vontade de definir a melhor estrutura. Uma das boas práticas do framework é trabalhar com a chamada "Application factory", ou "Fábrica de aplicações" (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/).

Quando você cria uma "app factory", você não precisa ter objetos globais e todo o processo de configuração e inicializações são efetuadas dentro da função da fábrica de app. Por exemplo:

```
def create_app(test_config=None):

    # cria e configura a aplicacao
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

    from .blueprint_um import views
    app.register_blueprint(views.bp)

    db.init_app(app)
    CORS(app)

    return app
```

Nesse exemplo eu crio uma fábrica com a função `create_app` e faço todas as minhas inicializações necessárias, incluindo o registro das minhas blueprints, que é muito importante. Esta função pode estar dentro de `__init__.py` que está dentro do pacote de aplicação principal do seu projeto. Esta é uma prática importante para que você consiga importar a sua função de criação do app sem dificuldades. Por exemplo, ao utilizar o `waitress` para rodar sua aplicação, basta executar
    `waitress-serve --call --listen=0.0.0.0:5000 app:create_app`
para que o `waitress` entenda que dentro do seu pacote `app` existe uma função `create_app` que pode ser chamada.

Enfim, existem muitas maneiras diferentes de fazer isso e é por isso que o flask é tão legal. Não deixa de conferir a documentação e implementações diferentes para que vocês conheça as possibilidades (eu também estou aprendendo muito ainda sobre o flask). Tenho um projetinho pequeno disponível lá no gitlab, se quiser pode dar uma olhada e até melhorar alguma coisa (tem muito a ser melhorado) https://gitlab.com/cavalcantigor/my-flaskr